# A question about if and if only condition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that $\lim _{x\to x_0} f(x)=l$ if and only if $\lim _{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=l$ and $\lim _{x\to x_0^-}f(x)=l$

i know how to prove in genearlly but here im trying to prove by sequential criterion

suppose $x_n \to x_0 $ and $f(x_n)\to l$ then

$x_n<x_0 $ and converges $x_0$  then $f(x_n)\to l$

Also $x_n>x_0 $ and converges $x_0$  then $f(x_n)\to l$

so both left and right limits are exists and equal to $l$

how to prove converse part

thank you so much i'm confusing these concepts so i m trying solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)=l$ and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}=x_0$. If the equality $x_n\geqslant x_0$ holds for all but finitely many $x_n$'s then since $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=l$, it is clear that $\lim_{n\to\infty}=x_0$. By the same argument, if the equality $x_n\leqslant x_0$ holds for all but finitely many $x_n$'s then $\lim_{n\to\infty}=x_0$ too. Otherwise, let $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be the sequence of all naturals $n$ such that $x_n\geqslant x_0$, by increasing order, and let $(m_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be the sequence of all naturals $n$ such that $x_n\leqslant x_0$, again by increasing order. Then$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{m_k})=l$$and it is easy to deduce from this that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=l$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=l$.

Comment: ...thank you again how you claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=l$ from last step ....sorry im no knowledge about this

Comment: There was a typo. I wrote$$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{m_k}=l,$$bbut I meant$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{m_k})=l.$$So, I proved that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=l.$$Is it clear now?

Comment: what i have understand is since both are subsequences and subsequence also converges to same limit  and then not understand

Comment: Note that those subsequences together form the whole sequence, in the sense that$$\mathbb{N}=\{n_k\,|\,k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{m_k\,|\,k\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$Therefore, if both limits $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})$ and  $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{m_k})$ are equal to $l$,  $\lim_{\to\infty}f(x_n)=l$ too.

Comment: carlos  santos...thank you so much for your patience

Comment: @InverseProblem I'm glad I could help.